# How to copy an embedded picture

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do I copy an embedded picture to a new image control?

Background: At runtime, I need to use one of two client logos as a header on various forms. The number of forms is at least three, but that number and the logo choice changes based upon choices made by the user. The user is one of many and various salesmen on various laptops out of my control, which may or may not have network access while the program is running. All I know is that we have at least Access 2007, or 2010, or 2013, or 2016, probably Windows... or Mac.
I have already embedded the logos into the database.

I would like to be able to `CreateControl acImage`, move it to the right spot(s) and then `MyImage.Picture = EmbeddedPicture`, but I am open to options.

How do you reference an already embedded picture in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already embedded the picture into database it will be available for all controls by name of picture and you can create new image on form using code like this:

```
Dim ctlImage As Image

DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acDesign

Set ctlImage = CreateControl("Form2", acImage, acDetail, , , 1000, 1000, 5000, 2000)
ctlImage.Picture = "image001.jpg"

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form2", acSaveYes
```

Before creating make sure that the picture embedded and you can see the picture file name in the dropdown listbox `Picture` property of any object, which has this property. Select "Emabedded" in `Picture Type` property first.

The easiest way to embed the picture is just once select picture file and change Picture Type to Embedded. After this the picture will be copied to one of the system tables of database and becomes available for any control with picture.

Please note, that for creating new controls the form should be opened in design mode. I would recommend to avoid this because this operation will generate an error if you compile your application to accde.

The better way is create picture object manually and just change Picture property depending on required picture. Also you can create few objects and make them visible/invisible at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. That is embarrassing. I couldn't imagine it was just as simple as using the previous file name. By the way, mine only works if I leave off the ".jpg" extension, but maybe I embedded it wrong in the first place.

Comment: Also, I noticed you edited the question to put my almost pseudo code inside code tags. Is there a tutorial somewhere that will show me at what point this community says that code becomes code enough to enclose it in tags?

Comment: First of all your question/answer should be easy to read and understand. Formatting helps with this. Here is formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and common recommendations about asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask